# Nativescript-camera крах приложения после выбора фотографии

Tags: android-camera, nativescript

Приложение использует плагин nativescript-camera.
Когда пользователь запускает камеру и делает подтверждение выбора фото, приложение само полноью перезапускается. Такая проблема встречаетс чаще всего на телефонах xiaomi, nokia, sony проверено на (Xiaomi (redmi 3s, redmi 4x) and Nokia (6.1)). Причем эта ошибка может произойти после того как пользователь сделает первое фото, а бывает после пятого или после дводцатого.
в консоле устройства получаю следующие ошибки:

*ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.TestCameraApp (pid 8370) has died: prev LA*

или

*ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.TestCameraApp (pid 615) has died: prev S*

Меттодом тестирования выяснил что эти ошибки появляются если использовать плагин nativescript-google-maps-sdk.

логи потока устройства можно посмотреть [сдесь](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fNlyjnhpzvDmo9_o6vu1hMzxDjuuNkqq)

ссылка на видео работы приложения на телефоне Xiaomi redmi 3s [сдесь](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18KupocmBGixBCse6XkI-7mt9idAZH6ga)

файл манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="__PACKAGE__"
          android:versionCode="10000"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="true"
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

функция вызова камеры:

```
onTakePictureTap(args) {
                console.log('camera start');
                let that = this;
                requestPermissions().then(
                    () => {
                        takePicture({ width: that.width, height: that.height, keepAspectRatio: that.keepAspectRatio, saveToGallery: that.saveToGallery, allowsEditing: that.allowsEditing }).
                        then((imageAsset) => {
                                that.cameraImage = imageAsset;
                                imageAsset.getImageAsync(function (nativeImage) {
                                    let scale = 1;
                                    let actualWidth = 0;
                                    let actualHeight = 0;
                                    if (imageAsset.android) {
                                        // get the current density of the screen (dpi) and divide it by the default one to get the scale
                                        scale = nativeImage.getDensity() / android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
                                        actualWidth = nativeImage.getWidth();
                                        actualHeight = nativeImage.getHeight();
                                    } else {
                                        scale = nativeImage.scale;
                                        actualWidth = nativeImage.size.width * scale;
                                        actualHeight = nativeImage.size.height * scale;
                                    }
                                    that.labelText = `Displayed Size: ${actualWidth}x${actualHeight} with scale ${scale}\n` +
                                        `Image Size: ${Math.round(actualWidth / scale)}x${Math.round(actualHeight / scale)}`;

                                    console.log(`${labelText}`);
                                });
                            },
                            (err) => {
                                console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
                            });
                    },
                    () => alert('permissions rejected')
                );
            }
```

pacege.json:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.TestCam",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.1.2"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "~7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "~8.0.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.2.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "vue-loader": "~15.4.0"
  },
  "gitHead": "1964ea9e8ca1a0518e0d6370781eedcf6c23db42",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключалась в строке 87 в файле camera.android.js в плагине камеры, при коментировани которой всё начинает работать стабильно.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var applicationModule = require("tns-core-modules/application/application");
var imageAssetModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-asset/image-asset");
var trace = require("tns-core-modules/trace/trace");
var platform = require("tns-core-modules/platform/platform");
var permissions = require("nativescript-permissions");
var REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 3453;
var useAndroidX = function () {
    return global.androidx && global.androidx.appcompat;
};
var FileProviderPackageName = useAndroidX() ? global.androidx.core.content : android.support.v4.content;
exports.takePicture = function (options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            if (!permissions.hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                reject(new Error("Application does not have permissions to use Camera"));
                return;
            }
            var types = require("tns-core-modules/utils/types");
            var utils = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");
            var saveToGallery_1 = true;
            var reqWidth_1 = 0;
            var reqHeight_1 = 0;
            var shouldKeepAspectRatio_1 = true;
            var density = utils.layout.getDisplayDensity();
            if (options) {
                saveToGallery_1 = types.isNullOrUndefined(options.saveToGallery) ? saveToGallery_1 : options.saveToGallery;
                reqWidth_1 = options.width ? options.width * density : reqWidth_1;
                reqHeight_1 = options.height ? options.height * density : reqWidth_1;
                shouldKeepAspectRatio_1 = types.isNullOrUndefined(options.keepAspectRatio) ? shouldKeepAspectRatio_1 : options.keepAspectRatio;
            }
            if (!permissions.hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                saveToGallery_1 = false;
            }
            var takePictureIntent = new android.content.Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            var dateStamp = createDateTimeStamp();
            var picturePath_1;
            var nativeFile = void 0;
            var tempPictureUri = void 0;
            if (saveToGallery_1) {
                picturePath_1 = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/Camera/" + "NSIMG_" + dateStamp + ".jpg";
                nativeFile = new java.io.File(picturePath_1);
            }
            else {
                picturePath_1 = utils.ad.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "NSIMG_" + dateStamp + ".jpg";
                nativeFile = new java.io.File(picturePath_1);
            }
            var sdkVersionInt = parseInt(platform.device.sdkVersion);
            if (sdkVersionInt >= 21) {
                tempPictureUri = FileProviderPackageName.FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationModule.android.context, applicationModule.android.nativeApp.getPackageName() + ".provider", nativeFile);
            }
            else {
                tempPictureUri = android.net.Uri.fromFile(nativeFile);
            }
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempPictureUri);
            if (options && options.cameraFacing === "front") {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            }
            else {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            }
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(utils.ad.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                var appModule_1 = require("tns-core-modules/application");
                appModule_1.android.off("activityResult");
                appModule_1.android.on("activityResult", function (args) {
                    var requestCode = args.requestCode;
                    var resultCode = args.resultCode;
                    if (requestCode === REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode === android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        if (saveToGallery_1) {
                            try {
                                var callback = new android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener({
                                    onScanCompleted: function (path, uri) {
                                        if (trace.isEnabled()) {
                                            trace.write("image from path " + path + " has been successfully scanned!", trace.categories.Debug);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                android.media.MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(appModule_1.android.context, [picturePath_1], null, callback);
                            }
                            catch (ex) {
                                if (trace.isEnabled()) {
                                    trace.write("An error occurred while scanning file " + picturePath_1 + ": " + ex.message + "!", trace.categories.Debug);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // var exif = new android.media.ExifInterface(picturePath_1);
                        // var orientation_1 = exif.getAttributeInt(android.media.ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                        // if (orientation_1 === android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                        //     rotateBitmap(picturePath_1, 90);
                        // }
                        // else if (orientation_1 === android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                        //     rotateBitmap(picturePath_1, 180);
                        // }
                        // else if (orientation_1 === android.media.ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                        //     rotateBitmap(picturePath_1, 270);
                        // }
                        // if (shouldKeepAspectRatio_1) {
                        //     var pictureWidth = exif.getAttributeInt(android.media.ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, 0);
                        //     var pictureHeight = exif.getAttributeInt(android.media.ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, 0);
                        //     var isPictureLandscape = pictureWidth > pictureHeight;
                        //     var areOptionsLandscape = reqWidth_1 > reqHeight_1;
                        //     if (isPictureLandscape !== areOptionsLandscape) {
                        //         var oldReqWidth = reqWidth_1;
                        //         reqWidth_1 = reqHeight_1;
                        //         reqHeight_1 = oldReqWidth;
                        //     }
                        // }
                        var asset = new imageAssetModule.ImageAsset(picturePath_1);
                        asset.options = {
                            width: reqWidth_1,
                            height: reqHeight_1,
                            keepAspectRatio: shouldKeepAspectRatio_1
                        };
                        resolve(asset);

                    }
                    else if (resultCode === android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        reject(new Error("cancelled"));
                    }
                });
                appModule_1.android.foregroundActivity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (reject) {
                reject(e);
            }
        }
    });
};
exports.isAvailable = function () {
    var utils = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");
    return utils.ad
        .getApplicationContext()
        .getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(android.content.pm.PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
};
exports.requestPermissions = function () {
    return permissions.requestPermissions([
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ]);
};
exports.requestPhotosPermissions = function () {
    return permissions.requestPermissions([
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    ]);
};
exports.requestCameraPermissions = function () {
    return permissions.requestPermissions([
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ]);
};
var createDateTimeStamp = function () {
    var result = "";
    var date = new Date();
    result = date.getFullYear().toString() +
        ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString()) +
        (date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + date.getDate().toString() : date.getDate().toString()) + "_" +
        date.getHours().toString() +
        date.getMinutes().toString() +
        date.getSeconds().toString();
    return result;
};
var rotateBitmap = function (picturePath, angle) {
    try {
        var matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        var bmOptions = new android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
        var oldBitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);
        var finalBitmap = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap, 0, 0, oldBitmap.getWidth(), oldBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        var out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(picturePath);
        finalBitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        if (trace.isEnabled()) {
            trace.write("An error occurred while rotating file " + picturePath + " (using the original one): " + ex.message + "!", trace.categories.Debug);
        }
    }
};
//# sourceMappingURL=camera.android.js.map
```